# Reacting to a specific user ID with an emoji in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been looking everywhere for an explanation, even reading the discord.js docs but nothing. Does anyone know how to react to a specific user id's message in discord.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get any message through the [`MessageManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=cache), or using [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) if the message is not cached. Fetching the message is a lot more restricting since you can only fetch the last 100 messages in the channel.

From there, you can [`find`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find)/[`filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) the message(s) you want by looking at their [`author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) property.

```js
// <channel> is a placeholder for the channel object you'd like to search

// get every cached message by a user in one channel
<channel>.messages.cache.filter(({ author }) => author.id === 'ID Here') 

<channel>.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then((messages) => {
 // same thing, but with uncached messages
 messages.filter(({ author }) => author.id === 'ID Here');
```

Each [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) also has a [`lastMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=lastMessage) property if that could come in handy for you.

```js
// <guild> is a placeholder for the guild object you'd like to search

// get the user's last message
guild.member('ID Here').lastMessage;
```